Race Conditions in ROS 2 Parameter Service: Security vs Performance Trade-offs
We've been investigating potential race conditions in ROS 2's parameter service on an NVIDIA Jetson Orin NX platform running ROS 2 Humble. Our findings reveal an interesting trade-off between thread safety and performance.
Test Setup
8 nodes running concurrently
Each node attempting parameter updates at 100Hz
MultiThreadedExecutor with 16 threads
Artificial delays to simulate processing time
Running on Jetson Orin NX with ROS 2 Humble
Key Findings
ROS 2's built-in parameter service appears to have robust thread synchronization that prevents race conditions even under extreme load
When implementing a custom parameter-like service without proper synchronization, we observe frequent race conditions:
[WARN] [param_race_node]: Race condition detected! Expected transition 1285->1286, but got 1285->1287
[WARN] [param_race_node]: Race condition detected! Expected transition 1292->1293, but got 1292->1294

Questions
Is this robust synchronization in the parameter service intentional design or a side effect?
Are there documented performance implications of this synchronization?
Are there any cases where we might want to bypass this synchronization for better performance?

The parameter service is specifically designed to be thread safe, as are the other core ROS interfaces.
Data corruption is potentially a catastrophic failure. As such not maintaining thread safety had not been considered.
There are rare use cases where allowing specific race conditions could enable higher throughput. But it needs to be carefully managed to make sure that the race conditions will never produce invalid data that will prevent correct operations of anything processing data downstream failing.
A user can hand off the data from the formal callbacks to their own threads and do whatever unsafe processing they want there. But if you do do that make sure to document it well so that others don't get caught by it.
